# Python 3.9.1 - Use of StandardScaler() to scale a single row of floats

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have typed in the following python commands along with sample data.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
>>> input_scaler = StandardScaler()
>>> data = numpy.array([1.24, 0.91, 1.77, 0.7])
>>> data.shape
(4,)
>>> reshapedData = data.reshape(1, 4)
>>> reshapedData
array([[1.24, 0.91, 1.77, 0.7 ]])
>>> input_scaler.fit(reshapedData)
StandardScaler()
>>> input_scaler.transform(reshapedData)
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.]])
>>>
```

However, the result is an array of zeros.

Actually in the above code, I am trying to scale a single row of float elements. However, the outcome is a row of zeros. Is this a bug or I am not grasping the usage of python function fully?

Any suggestions how to correct it or do it differently?

Comment: What result do you expect for this input, and why?

Comment: I expect the transformed data to be of zero-mean and unit variance for my machine learning algorithm to work well. Where I expect "mean = 1.24+0.91+1.77+0.7/4 = 1.155" and "scale = ???" (the python process of calculating the "scale" is not mentioned anywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reshaped the data wrongly, with this:

```
data.reshape(1, 4)
array([[1.24, 0.91, 1.77, 0.7 ]])
```

You have a dataframe that has 4 variables, and 1 observation, of course after scaling you get all zeros

You need to do:

```
reshapedData = data.reshape(-1,1)


array([[1.24],
       [0.91],
       [1.77],
       [0.7 ]])

input_scaler.fit(reshapedData)
input_scaler.transform(reshapedData)

array([[ 0.21045472],
       [-0.60660477],
       [ 1.52270177],
       [-1.12655172]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I am currently working on a machine learning algorithm where I want the data to be of zero mean and unit variance. I could scale the "training" data easily which has X variables and y observations. However, in the "prediction" process, I have X variables and 1 observation. In that case I put that one observation in a row and was trying to standardize it. But as you could see, that approach did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fit single observation and then scale the same.
Instead, you should compute the mean and std. dev values for your training data and then use this mean and std. dev to scale your observations.

Please try the following steps:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scale_fit = scaler.fit(use_training_data) #save the mean and std. dev computed for your data.
scaled_data = scale_fit.transform(use_data_to_be_scaled) #use the above saved values to scale your single observation or batch observations.
```

For more detailed information you can refer to:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit